# Shell_exec function working fine but after running it not allowing other activity or function in PHP

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have a report download function in my website. It taking almost more than 15 minutes to complete the download. While this function running my website not allowing to open other pages or other activity in my website. I also dont want to use cron job becuase it is not regular task.

To overcome this I have written shell_exec to call upon user button clicks and send an email with attachment once completed.. It is working fine but it also not allowing user to open home page also still it completes in backend also. Please suggest anyone how to achieve this.

My main moto is user once click on download button i have to call one function in backend and user must do other activity like opening home page or search other anything.

```
public function downloadtest_new() {
    $data = $_POST;
    $post_data = http_build_query($data);
    $url = base_url()."home/downloadreport_new";
    $command = "curl -X POST -d '$post_data' '$url'";
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
}
```

In downloadreport_new there is a logic to retrieve data from sql and send it as csv to the user email. Function is working fine but user not able to any other task while it completes.

Comment: After click on download button user will not able to access other pages. it is keep on loading.

Comment: You need another process to send your email in the background so your webserver can finish serving the request. Search for "background processing" or "queue processing" to get some ideas.

Comment: That is main use of shell_exec to run the process in backend.

Comment: Do `yourcommand  >> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to run the script in the _background_. `shell_exec` normaly waits for an return code of the command you run, so its not really an _background_ task, you just execute an command.  With piping the output `>>` and set the command as background task with `&` shell_exec waits no more, but the command will run in background